# Windows Firewall: 2 Sets of remote inbound rules deployed by 2 different GPO's

Tags: windows, firewall, group-policy

I'm looking to create 1 gpo with f/w inbound access rules for just our management server ip's at a high level in the group policy tree. As you drill down under our sites I'm looking to create a 2nd gpo with inbound access rules for a separate set of ip's. I have both of gpo's linked and have my server in the security filtering and doing a gpo query I see both policies applied. Unfortunately when I go to the firewall on my server the higher referenced gpo rule is the only one showing.

If I create another firewall rule unrelated to inbound ip's (say adding just a program rule) that one will show up. Is what I'm asking even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are they the same name?

Comment: The gpo's are different names as are the firewall rules. I tried using the same f/w rule name but that didn't have an effect.

Comment: I have multiple GPOs with different firewall rules both inbound and outbound with different restrictions (program, scope, port, ip ranges) and it all works as advertised. I don't understand what kind of overlap, if any, your rules are having.

Comment: But do you have multiple gpo's with different scopes applying to the same server?

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: Are you using the firewall group policy settings under "Administrative Templates -> Network -> Network Connections" or the ones under "Windows Settings -> Security Settings" ?  Have you double-checked that none of the OUs have the "Block Inheritance" flag set?

Comment: I'm using the policy settings under windows settings > security settings. There is definitely no blocked inheritance. When doing a gpresult I see my 2nd gpo is applied.

Comment: @Svenguard yes I have GPOs that are different scopes with firewall rules under security settings. Highest applies to all linked at domain, then the next GPO is WMI filtered and the closest one is limited by security group. Have you tried disabling the higher level rule to see if the closest GPO rules apply successfully?